# How do I configure Tomcat HAProxy to forward from localhost:8080/path to 1.2.3.4:8080/path?

Tags: tomcat, haproxy

All the HAProxy tutorials give examples only about port 80 and some default path. How  do I configure Tomcat HAProxy to forward from `localhost:8080/path` to `1.2.3.4:8080/path`? I can't figure it out in the config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to proxy all requests coming to `/path` to `1.2.3.4:8080/path`, you could do something like this:

```
frontend http_fe
    bind *:443
    option forwardfor
    use_backend be_path if { path_beg /path }
    default_backend default_be

backend be_default
    ...

backend be_path
    mode http 
    option forwardfor
    server srv01 1.2.3.4:8080
```